# Solid angle measurement conditions for radiant intensity specification in IR-LED's data-sheets

Tags: led, measurement, infrared, optoelectronics, optics

For some IR-LED's their data-sheets state Radiant Intensity and the conditions under which
that number was obtained, indicating also which solid angle was used for the measurement.

For example, this 15 Deg LED was measured with a solid angle of 0.01 sr 
http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic4/00239136_0.pdf/SFH%204258.pdf

and this 3 Deg with a solid angle of 0.001 sr

http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic0/00239538_0.pdf/SFH%204550.pdf

This corresponds to CIE standard B (0.01 sr) and A (0.001 sr) conditions.

But for example data-sheets for this two don't give at which solid angle the radiant intensity was measured. I can only guess that the measurement was probably done with 0.01 sr, that is CIE condition A was used.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/83398/vsmy2850.pdf

http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/201407061539021388.pdf

How can one know at which solid angle radiant intensity measurement is performed, is there some standard or rule the manufacturers follow that defines which solid angle is used for radiant intensity measurments depending in the LED half angle ?

Eg. LED' with >=10Deg half angle are measured with 0.001 sr (CIE A) and 
LED's with half angle greater than 10Deg are measured with 0.01 sr (CIE B) ?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, very few LED vendors follow any standard with regard to their specifications. A telephone call with their applications engineer may bring clarity, but more often than not, testing in your own lab will be required if this is a significant parameter for your application.

Comment: But stating radiant intensity without any reference to solid angle is useless. I don't understand why the vendors give this number in the datasheet then ?